# Adding to a Shared Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, php-toolkit

My company is trying to add to a shared data extension via FuelSDK in PHP and are running into some issues targeting the shared data extension. We've made sure that the following is set up:

- Permissions for the Business Unit are all set to allow
- The external key for the Data Extension is set
- The web form field names match the data extension fields

We have been able to add to a regular data extension with no issues, and have even created a separate testing data extension with the same information to ensure that things are set the same.

We still cannot seem to target the Shared Data Extension, and have been unsuccessful in finding anything in the documentation that directs us to the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Shared DE u need Enterprise 2.0 account.
    U can only create shared DE using parent BU legacy token..

Comment: Thanks foe sharing that Saravanan, do you know any references to documentation that could help improve this answer ?

Comment: Sorry man i don't have